# Cypress wait for API after button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

I've made a React app, which all works perfectly and I'm now writing some end to end tests using Cypress.

The React app all works on the same url, it's not got any routes, and api calls from inside the app are handled through button clicks.

The basis of the app is the end user selects some options, then presses filter to view some graphs that are dependant on the selected options.

```
cy.get('button').contains('Filter').click()
```

When the button is pressed in cypress, it runs the 3 api calls which return as expected, but looking over the cypress docs there is no easy way unless I use inline `cy.wait(15000)` which isn't ideal, as sometimes they return a lot faster, and sometimes they return slower, depending on the selected options.

**Edit 1**
I've tried using server and route:

```
cy.server({ method: 'GET' });
cy.route('/endpoint1*').as('one')
cy.route('/endpoint2*').as('two')
cy.route('/endpoint3*').as('three')
cy.get('button').contains('Filter').click()
cy.wait(['@one', '@two', '@three'], { responseTimeout: 15000 })
```

Which gives me the error:

```
CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: 'one'. No request ever occurred.
```

**After further investigation**

Changing from `responseTimeout` to just `timeout` fixed the error.

```
cy.server({ method: 'GET' });
cy.route('/endpoint1*').as('one')
cy.route('/endpoint2*').as('two')
cy.route('/endpoint3*').as('three')
cy.get('button').contains('Filter').click()
cy.wait(['@one', '@two', '@three'], { timeout: 15000 }).then(xhr => {
  // Do what you want with the xhr object
})
```

Comment: Have you run tests without wait ? I think my tests passed because cypress take care of wait.

Comment: They just go to the next action with out the wait.

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.html#Waiting

Comment: @BostonStar I thought this would be the solution when I was on it earlier, but it didn't work as I expected, it was timing out after 5000, maybe needs the timeout parameter like in the below answer. I'll try it again as this is the tidyer option really.

Comment: Anyone who is facing that it waits till the timeout, endpoint should be mentioned as `/endpoint2**` notice the two stars - https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Without-Stubbing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like you'll want to [wait for the routes](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#Alias).  Something like this:

```
cy.server();
cy.route('GET', '/api/route1').as('route1');
cy.route('GET', '/api/route2').as('route2');
cy.route('GET', '/api/route3').as('route3');

cy.get('button').contains('Filter').click();

// setting timeout because you mentioned it can take up to 15 seconds.
cy.wait(['@route1', '@route2', 'route3'], { responseTimeout: 15000 });

// This won't execute until all three API calls have returned
cy.get('#something').click();
```

Comment: Looks like exactly what I want, I tried it before, but didn't have the timeout on it, so explains exactly why it didn't work. I'll see Monday and reply then. Cheers.

Comment: I've edited the question with what happens trying this method.

Comment: @Geoff I see that `timeout` worked for you instead.  You're likely on an older version of Cypress, that was split out in version 3.1.3.  you'll need to change it to `responseTimeout` once you upgrade.  https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog.html#3-1-3

Comment: `"cypress": "^3.3.2"` strange... although I have got this working with putting `responseTimeout: 15000` in cypress.json. `timeout` does work on it's own in the wait command.

Answer (score 9):

Rather than using a `.wait` you can use a timeout parameter. That way if it finished faster, you don't have to wait.

```
cy.get('button').contains('Filter', {timeout: 15000}).click()
```

This is mentioned as one of the options parameters [in the official docs here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Arguments).

Comment: I'll try that when I'm next on it. Cheers.

Comment: Your wait probably goes after the bit of code you posted, in which case you would want to add the timeout to the next assertion. It works the same way. Almost all of the cypress methods have a timeout parameter, not just 'contains'. Paste your next assertion in to question if you are having trouble.

Comment: This works, but it's not very graceful the method in Brendans answer is how it's intended to be done with Cypress.

Comment: I disagree. Your answer assumes you are working with restful APIs. When this question was first posted, this was not the case. My approach work with web sockets, streams, and graphql. More robust.

Comment: Define graceful. You added 5 extra lines and achieved the same as what I did in 15 colocated characters. Please leave both answers up because they are both useful approaches for different situations.

Comment: It adds more code, sure, but the added code makes it a lot clearer what's intended to be done. It also gives the test access to the responses from the api calls.

Comment: I agree, but my point is that this is a different requirement, not a better one. Perhaps change the question title to 'Cypress wait for rest api response' to better direct other people searching for the same issue.

Comment: Taken on board, question changed.

Answer (score 2):

`cy.server()` and `cy.route()` are deprecated in **Cypress 6.0.0** In a future release, support for `cy.server()` and `cy.route()` will be removed. Consider using `cy.intercept()` instead.

this worked for me...

ex:-
[see the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbwS8.png)

```
    cy.intercept('GET', 'http://localhost:4001/meta').as('route');
    cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .nav-link').click();
    cy.contains('Filter');
    cy.wait(['@route'], { responseTimeout: 15000 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    cy.contains('button', 'Save').click();
    cy.get('[data-ng-show="user.manage"]', { timeout: 10000 }).should('be.visible').then(() => {
      `cy.get('[data-ng-show="user.manage"]').click();
   })
```